# He helps me (to) be succeeded

Tags: sentence-choice

Which one of these sentences is correct?

1. He helps me be succeeded
2. He helps me to be succeeded

Comment: [buzzer: the sentences are not grammatical at all. Please consult a dictionary.] succeed is a verb, and successful is the adjective.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean *He helps me to be successful,* neither is correct. Use either that or *to succeed.*

If you *are succeeded* by someone, they follow you in a particular role. King George VI was *succeeded* by his daughter, Queen Elizabeth II.

Comment: Is it that you want to know how 'be succeeded' differs from 'to be succeeded'?

Answer (score -3):

Regarding the structure of your sentences, both sentences are correct.
He helps me eat/ walk/ read.
He helps me to eat/ to walk/ to read.